# Does PostgreSQL use indexes for queries with OR?

Tags: postgresql

For instance, I've got a Rails app with an index on a column called `archived_at`. The query is an OR that checks if `archived_at` IS NULL OR `archived_at` is in the future (it's a timestamp column).

Does using an OR bypass indices? I've heard something about that before.

Comment: I suggest that you use `EXPLAIN` to see how Postgres is using your indexes: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-explain.html

Answer (score 0):

PG can use Bitmap Index Scan for this operation.

If your rows are (more or less) well organized in the physical table (for example, archived_at is the date of insertion in the table, and there are few deletions) this process is extremely efficient.